# Heroku push rejected, Could not communicate with vendor, please try again later

Tags: django, git, heroku

Im trying to make the first push into Heroku git for my first app, and I'm keep getting this error:

```
-----> Compiled slug size: 29.9MB
-----> Launching... !     Heroku push rejected, Could not communicate with vendor, please try again later
```

I'm trying to deploy django app. this error comes after installing all the python packages and 'Discovering process types'.
My connectivity is 100% fine.

any ideas?  couldn't find anything in the help center.

thanks!

Comment: sounds like an intermittent heroku issue. please file support tickets: http://help.heroku.com

Comment: Same problem here, I'm trying to deploy a rails app.

Comment: seems to be fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue with provisioning databases: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/521

Should be fixed now.