# git push heroku master fails even if everything seems to be fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

This is the console, everything seems to work fine until the launching module of `git push`
What's the problem?

```
# Rails Environment Configuration.

---
git:
  user.name:  Theofilos_Mouratidis
  user.email: mtheofilos@gmail.com
  version:    git version 1.7.9.msysgit.0

ruby:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe
  version:    ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

rails:
  bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rails.bat
  version:    Rails 3.2.13

ssh:
  public_key_location: C:\Users\acer/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  public_key_contents: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAvrft8l3K12KfGo9uXrFfK
YhiQW2mHxoBIWaHXmFec7/14bx3awQLb8rG4zYZdrAWijy86vOJlk7jm07amwrOPKjkTYkIkHoclEu1y
wYS3PEPBCLe5gpPMIoej22T7X3PqLfLza3MpW6HSE3TOOT+dG74Ms0T6v8YOFQ19SiGwKTIAyF7Mczx0
xet9rKxxnRQuvyqByWq+ZOBSFao5zlqsfh8QWwGGh3thsjNo7ICDfP8tQmu57jjOTcjZC3st0tEzUoNK
zdXdz5PDLRo2fSXTKG7PhadLmLn4Cg4fhY6sOraXeYrzt9pVp0b9SYnWqTYNhi74kSx0z1i5lfna6eXk
w== Theofilos Mouratidis <mtheofilos@gmail.com>



C:\Sites>cd tama

C:\Sites\tama>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: mtheofilos@gmail.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Authentication successful.

C:\Sites\tama>git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   .idea/workspace.xml
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

C:\Sites\tama>git add .

C:\Sites\tama>git commit
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.

C:\Sites\tama>git commit -m "nothing"
[master cd12603] nothing
 1 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)

C:\Sites\tama>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 172, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (152/152), done.
Writing objects: 100% (172/172), 210.47 KiB | 67 KiB/s, done.
Total 172 (delta 41), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby/Rails app detected
remote: -----> WARNING: Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Wind
ows.
remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properl
y.
remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app
.
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/
bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Resolving dependencies...
remote:        Installing rake (10.0.4)
remote:        Installing i18n (0.6.1)
remote:        Installing multi_json (1.7.2)
remote:        Installing activesupport (3.2.13)
remote:        Installing builder (3.0.4)
remote:        Installing activemodel (3.2.13)
remote:        Installing erubis (2.7.0)
remote:        Installing journey (1.0.4)
remote:        Installing rack (1.4.5)
remote:        Installing rack-cache (1.2)
remote:        Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
remote:        Installing hike (1.2.2)
remote:        Installing tilt (1.3.7)
remote:        Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
remote:        Installing actionpack (3.2.13)
remote:        Installing mime-types (1.23)
remote:        Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
remote:        Installing treetop (1.4.12)
remote:        Installing mail (2.5.3)
remote:        Installing actionmailer (3.2.13)
remote:        Installing arel (3.0.2)
remote:        Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
remote:        Installing activerecord (3.2.13)
remote:        Installing activeresource (3.2.13)
remote:        Installing authlogic (3.3.0)
remote:        Using bundler (1.3.2)
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
remote:        Installing execjs (1.4.0)
remote:        Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
remote:        Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
remote:        Installing json (1.7.7)
remote:        Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
remote:        Installing thor (0.18.1)
remote:        Installing railties (3.2.13)
remote:        Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
remote:        Installing jquery-rails (2.2.1)
remote:        Installing pg (0.15.1)
remote:        Installing rails (3.2.13)
remote:        Installing sass (3.2.8)
remote:        Installing sass-rails (3.2.6)
remote:        Installing uglifier (2.0.1)
remote:        Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
remote:        Post-install message from rdoc:
remote:        Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby r
doc/ri data:
remote:        <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
remote:        = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally
remote: -----> Rails plugin injection
remote:        Injecting rails_log_stdout
remote:        Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types      -> (none)
remote:        Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker
remote:
remote: -----> Compiled slug size: 9.4MB
remote: -----> Launching... !     Heroku push rejected, Could not communicate wi
th vendor, please try again later
remote:
To git@heroku.com:tamagotchi-connect.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:tamagotchi-connect.git'

C:\Sites\tama>
```

This is the `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
end

gem 'authlogic'
```

Comment: It might be a Heroku issue, it seems more people are having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209967/heroku-push-rejected-could-not-communicate-with-vendor-please-try-again-later

Comment: yeah, heroku issue. file a support ticket http://help.heroku.com

Comment: Should be fixed, try again please: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/521

Comment: @ctshryock git issue, not db issue.

Comment: @kch, the issue was manifesting itself here through `git push`, but if you see the the `Heroku push rejected, Could not communicate with vendor, please try again later` error, that's caused by the DB provisioning mentioned in the incident report.

Comment: yeah you are right, it now worked

Comment: Please close this question if everything is working.